# WordPress. Как сложить значения нескольких полей созданных в Custom Content Type от Crockoblock?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Как сложить значения нескольких полей созданных в Custom Content Type от Crockoblock?
Я создал Custom Content Type - Игрок, у которого помимо персональных данных есть поля с цифровыми значениями его скилов (от 0 до 100).

Например:
Сила - 98
Скорость - 81
Ловкость - 78 ... итд
Получается: 98+81+78 = (результат сложения вывести на сайт)

Посоветуйте Плагин, который поможет выбрать и сложить необходимые значения, чтобы вывести сумму данных показателей в профайле данного игрока. Надеюсь понятно объяснил) Спасибо!
https://basket24.online/akramov/ Здесь пример

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Проще говоря нужно вывести сумму значений определенных полей, которые заполнены в ручную при создании профайла игрока

Comment: https://basket24.online/akramov/ Здесь пример